# Python - can't start new thread, it's my fault I just can't figure out how to fix it

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I've found other questions similar to this but they're subtly different that I can't figure out how to answer my own question...  I know I'm creating too many threads I just don't know how to stop that!

I have a routine that processes software builds by looping over each build (lets say the maximum number of builds is 10); for each build I loop over two platforms (win64, lnx64) and for each platform I loop over three directories (10 x 2 x 3 = 60 directories).

For each directory I copy the files from one network location to another.  To copy the files I use a file called bld_copy.py that has a function called cpBuild(sourceDir, DestinationDir) (which is imported to the calling routine).

cpBuild will construct a list of files in sourceDir (using os.path.walk) and a list of associated files in DestinationDir and use a queue and threading to copy the files.  The cpBuild function is a general function that is called from other files that need to copy code from A to B, it's used quite heavily.  The function that does the threaded copying within bld_copy.py is as follows:

```
def copyFilesThread(fullFileList):
  # fullFileList contains a list of files to copy [(fileFromA, fileToA), (fileFromB, fileToB), ...]

  copyFileQueue = Queue.Queue()  # Create a job queue so we can copy the files in parallel

  class copyFileThread(threading.Thread):
    # Inherit from threading and overload the __init__ method so we can pass in the queue object
    def __init__(self, queue):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
      while True:
        filesToCopy = self.queue.get()
        try:
          sourceFile = filesToCopy[0]
          destinationFile = filesToCopy[1]
          if sourceFile and destinationFile:
            if os.path.islink(sourceFile):
              if not os.path.islink(destinationFile):
                linkto = os.readlink(sourceFile)
                os.symlink(linkto, destinationFile)
            else:
              try:
                shutil.copy(sourceFile, destinationFile)
              except shutil.Error as e:
                print('Error: shutil.copy: %s' % e)
              except IOError as e:
                print('Error: shutil IOError: %s' % e.strerror)
        except Exception as e:
          print '        %s' %(e)
        self.queue.task_done()

  # Start twenty threads and pass them the queue instance
  for x in xrange (20):
    t = copyFileThread(copyFileQueue)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()

  # Populate the queue and thread pool and load it up by looping over the fullFileList list
  for filesToCopy in fullFileList:
    copyFileQueue.put(filesToCopy)

  # wait on the queue until everything has been processed
  copyFileQueue.join()
```

My issue is this routine ends up being called up to sixty times.  I'm noticing on Linux that if I use ps -fLu  that each time my outer loop is finished I have an extra 120 threads.  When multiplying this by 10 outer loops I potentially have up to 1200 threads hence why the routine bombs out with:

```
can't start new thread
```

Given the way this has been setup, is there a way for me to either re-use the threads or have them go out of scope... (which is what I would have assumed would happen).  I'm no expert with this and would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Are you running the *function* 60 times or the *program* using the function?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, it's the separate program that calls the function 60 times, ultimately via the cpBuild function, so in the main program I do:

    from bld_copy2 import cpBuild

And then call it in the nested loop with:

    cpBuild(sourcePath, destinationPath)